# Update a mixed type activity in GetStream.IO using the java stream client loses the type attribute

Tags: getstream-io

I have taken the MixedType example code that comes with the java stream client (https://github.com/GetStream/stream-java) and added a update step using updateActivities.  After the update the activity stored in stream loses the 'type' attribute. Jackson uses this attribute when you get the activities again and it is deserialising them.

So I get:

`Exception in thread "main" Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:60016', transport: 'socket'
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Could not resolve type id 'null' into a subtype of [simple type, class io.getstream.client.apache.example.mixtype.MixedType$Match]
 at [Source: org.apache.http.client.entity.LazyDecompressingInputStream@29ad44e3; line: 1, column: 619] (through reference chain: io.getstream.client.model.beans.StreamResponse["results"]->java.util.ArrayList[1])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.unknownTypeException(DeserializationContext.java:849)`

See here where I have updated the example:

https://github.com/puntaa/stream-java/blob/master/stream-repo-apache/src/test/java/io/getstream/client/apache/example/mixtype/MixedType.java

Any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is originated by Jackson which cannot get the actual instance type of an object inside the collection due to the Java *type erasure*, if you want to know more about it please read this issue: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/336 (which also provides some possible workarounds).

The easiest way to solve it, would be to manually force the value of the property `type` from within the subclass as shown in the example below:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = VolleyballMatch.class, name = "volley"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = FootballMatch.class, name = "football")
})
static abstract class Match extends BaseActivity {
    private String type;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
}

static class VolleyballMatch extends Match {
    private int nrOfServed;
    private int nrOfBlocked;

    public VolleyballMatch() {
        super.type = "volley";
    }

    public int getNrOfServed() {
        return nrOfServed;
    }

    public void setNrOfServed(int nrOfServed) {
        this.nrOfServed = nrOfServed;
    }

    public void setNrOfBlocked(int nrOfBlocked) {
        this.nrOfBlocked = nrOfBlocked;
    }

    public int getNrOfBlocked() {
        return nrOfBlocked;
    }
}

static class FootballMatch extends Match {
    private int nrOfPenalty;
    private int nrOfScore;

    public FootballMatch() {
        super.type = "football";
    }

    public int getNrOfPenalty() {
        return nrOfPenalty;
    }

    public void setNrOfPenalty(int nrOfPenalty) {
        this.nrOfPenalty = nrOfPenalty;
    }

    public int getNrOfScore() {
        return nrOfScore;
    }

    public void setNrOfScore(int nrOfScore) {
        this.nrOfScore = nrOfScore;
    }
}
```